# Why JFrame is able to be displayed only in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I have developed a Swing Java Application with only one `JFrame` with a `JPanel` inside it.

When I run that in Eclipse it is displaying correctly, but when I try to export as a Runnable Jar or Export to NetBeans it doesn't display the inner `JPanel`, just a empty `JFrame`.

Running in Eclipse

[image]

Running in JVM or NetBeans:

[image]

**Code**

```
public LoadJPanel(){
    Font_PalMap_rest = getCustomFont(ID_CODE_FONT_REST);
    Font_PalMap_title = getCustomFont(ID_CODE_FONT_TITLE);
    ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon(Background_path).getImage());
    btnAddAndroid = getButtonConfig(ID_CODE_BUTTON_ADD_ANDROID_DEVICE);
    btnSendSMS = getButtonConfig(ID_CODE_BUTTON_SEND_SMS_AUTO);
    btnOpenFolder  = getButtonConfig(ID_CODE_BUTTON_OPEN_FOLDER);
    JLabel label_lembretePalmas = getLabelConfig(ID_CODE_LABEL_TITLE);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("LembretePalmas");
    textArea = getTextAreaConfig(ID_CODE_DISPLAYING_PROCESS_AREA);
    scrollPane = getScrollPaneConfig(ID_CODE_DISPLAYING_PROCESS_AREA,textArea);
    panel.add(btnAddAndroid);
    panel.add(btnSendSMS);
    panel.add(label_lembretePalmas);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
    panel.add(btnOpenFolder);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(Icon_path).getImage());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    setServer();
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Why does this question have tags for two different IDEs?  4) A `JComponent` typicaly does not need to be set visible.  Just top level containers. 5) Don't use `ImageIcon` for loading images  IT will fail silently.  Use `ImageIO` for a helpful stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem.

It works when I copy the image's folder in the same path that the JAR is located.

I added `System.getProperty("user.dir"));` too at the beginning of the image's path.

Comment: Application resources should become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.  -1 for using a 'hack' to get around a problem that has better fixes.  ..and the edit from a moment ago is an uncompilable code snippet, not an MCVE.  Please carefully read the content of links offered.